# While loop cycle not satisfying requirements

Tags: python

I am measuring parameters on a battery (current, voltage, etc..) using an analogue to digital converter. The “While loop” cycle contains also the measurements functions which are not shown in this context because are not part of my question.

With the code here below, I am attempting to calculate Ampere/hours on each iteration of the cycle (Ahinst) simply multiplying the measured current by the elapsed time between two measurements. I am also summing up the Ah to get a cumulative value (TotAh) drained from the battery. This last value is shown only when the current (P2) is negative (battery not in charging mode). When the current (P2) reverse into charging mode I clear TotAh and just show 0.

```
timeMeas=[]
currInst=[]
Ah=[]
TotAh=0

while(True):
    try:

 #measurements routines are also running here
    #......................

 #Ah() in development
     
     if (P2 < 0):                #if current is negative (discharging)
        Tnow = datetime.now()    #get time_start reference to calculate elapsed time until next current measure  
        timeMeas.append (Tnow)   #save time_start
        currInst.append (P2)     #save current at time_start
                
    
     if (len(currInst) >1):              #if current measurements are two
        elapsed=(timeMeas[1]-timeMeas[0]).total_seconds() #calculate time elapsed between two mesurements
        Ahinst=currInst[1]/3600*elapsed  #calculate Ah per time interval
        Ah.append(Ahinst)                #save Ah per time interval
        TotAh=round(sum(Ah),3)* -1       #update cumulative Ah
        timeMeas=[]                      #cleanup data in array
        currInst=[]                      #cleanup data in array
        
     elif (P2 > 0):
            TotAh=0
            Ah=[]
            
            
            
            time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
```

The code is working but obviously is not giving me the correct result because in the second “if”condition I always clear the two arrays (timeMeas and CurrInst). Since the calculation requires at least two actual measurements “if (len(currInst)>1) ” to work, clearing the two arrays cause to lose one measurement at every iteration of the cycle. I have considered shifting the values position from 0 to 1 in the arrays at every iteration, but this would cause calculation mistakes when the cycle is restarted after the value P2 is reversed to charging and then discharging mode again.

I am very rusty with coding and doing this for hobby. I am battling to find a solution to calculate “Ahinst” at every cycle with the actual values.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The code as shown will result in an error due to the lack of indentation between `while(True):` and `try:` There's also other indentation errors in the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sorry for that. It has to do with the copy past. I try to fix it. However the script is running on my Pi

Comment: Bit of a guess, but I think you'd want `timeMeas = [timeMeas[-1]]` and `currInst = [currInst[-1]]`. That way, the last value of your measurements is the first (and only) value of your next measurement.

Comment: @9769953, thats very true. I need to change that for sure. I still need to clear the arrays at some stage. I am not sure if that will be enough to get the measurements correct. I try. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to keep two measurements (current and previous) you can keep arrays of size two, and have `idx = 1 - idx` at the end of the loop to have it flip-flop between 0 and 1.

```py
timeMeas = [None, None]
currInst = [None, None]
TotAh = 0.0

idx = 0

while True:  # no need for parentheses
    try:     
     if (P2 < 0):
        Tnow = datetime.now()
        timeMeas[idx] = Tnow
        currInst[idx] = P2
    
     if currInst[1] is not None:  #meaning we have at least two measurements
        elapsed = (timeMeas[idx]-timeMeas[1-idx]).total_seconds()
        TotAh + = currInst[idx]/3600*elapsed

     elif (P2 > 0):  # is "elif" really correct here?
            TotAh = 0.0
            # Do we want to reset these, too?
            timeMeas = [None, None]
            currInst = [None, None]

            # should this really be inside the elif?
            time.sleep(1)

     idx = 1 - idx

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
```

In some sense, it would be simpler to have two `dict` variables `curr` and `prev`, and set `prev = None` when you start or reset them. Then simply set `curr = prev` at the end of the loop, and populate `curr` with new values in each iteration, like `curr['when'] = datetime.now()` and `curr['measurement'] = P2`.

Comment: Thanks a million. I am trying to adopt your script. But there is something not working with the time elapsed. https://file.io/YxSuKQzidd5d It goes back and forward

Comment: The link says "file deleted".

Comment: I suppose `elapsed = abs((timeMeas[1]-timeMeas[0]).total_seconds())` could be replaced with `elapsed = (timeMeas[idx]-timeMeas[1-idx]).total_seconds()`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I believe the `abs()` should no longer be necessary so I took out that, too.